# ASMX with attributes on method request element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am trying to write a mock service to imitate a 3rd party web service I have no access to until production.

Say I have method 'Foo' which takes parameter 'WidgetName'. The request body might look something like this:

```
<Foo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <WidgetName>Gadget</WidgetName>
        ...
</Foo>
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<Foo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" WidgetName="Gadget">
 ...
</Foo>
```

Notice that 'WidgetName' is an attribute of 'Foo'. I can decorate the parameter with `[XmlAttribute]` like so:

```
[WebMethod]
...
public string Foo([XmlAttribute]string WidgetName) {
  //...
}
```

But when it is all said and done results in..

```
XmlSerializer attribute System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute is not valid in sourceSystemType. Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true.
```

Well `.Bare` isn't what I want (opposite of `.Wrapped`), right? Since that results in `<Foo ..></Foo>` disappearing altogether. If I do set to 'Bare' I get this error (with the complete, real code) when trying to update the web service reference:

`There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:48319/FooWS/FooWS.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. The request failed with the error message...` which says `Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.`

The error updating goes away once I remove `[XmlAttribute]` from the `Foo(string WidgetName)` I just don't know where to go from here.